# C# - Check and notify of boolean value changed

Tags: c#, events

Good day all

I am struggling to familiarize myself with Events, I just can't seem to get my head around the concept, after quite a few tutorials and videos, I am still lost, thus I will be specific about my problem.

In short, a thread pings an IP, if the ping reports a success,

> ServerOnline = (ping == success ) ? true : false;

The event listener should "listen" for a variable change, get the variable and process accordingly.

A example based on the code below would be of an immense help.

```
class tcp_connector
{
    bool ServerOnline

    void thread_checkServer()
    {
        //do code
        ServerOnline = true;
        //notify of variable change
    }    
}

class tcp_sender
{
    //when ServerOnline bool = true
    //button.color = color.green;   
}
```

Comment: are you on win forms? If so you can assign the value on a textbox and "play" with the textbox changed event

Answer (score 3):

You can declare an `event` in your `tcp_connector` that you raise if `ServerOnline` changes like this:

```
class tcp_connector
{
    // standard event pattern
    public event EnventHandler ServerOnlineChanged;
    protected virtual void OnServerOnlineChanged
    {
        EventHandler handler = ServerOnlineChanged; // for thread safety
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private bool _serverOnline;
    public bool ServerOnline // implement as property
    {
        get { return _serverOnline; }
        set {
            if (_serverOnline == value) return;
            _serverOnline = value;
            OnServerOnlineChanged(); // raise event
            }
    }

    void thread_checkServer()
    {
        //do code

        // be sure to use the property ServerOnline, not the
        // field _serverOnline! 
        // the property setter will raise ServerOnlineChangedEvent
        ServerOnline = true;
    }    
}
```

And then you can consume that `event` in your `tcp_sender` like this:

```
class tcp_sender
{
    private tcp_connector _connector;

    public tcp_sender()
    {
        _connector = new tcp_connector();
        // subscribe to event
        _connector.ServerOnlineChanged += tcp_connector_ServerOnlineChanged;
    }

    // the event handler for the ServerOnlineChanged event
    private void tcp_connector_ServerOnlineChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_connector.ServerOnline)
           button.color = color.green;
    }
}
```

This is not really a "listener" that watches your property `ServerOnline`, but by seperating it into a *field* and a *property* you can recognize changes and raise the specified event.